# How to filter files with date from a folder in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have c# code to get the pdf files from a folder.

```
string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(EnvSettingsTools.FilePath.ToString(), "*.pdf")
                                 .Select(path => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))
                                 .ToArray();
```

How can i use this code to get the files by filter by date. The file format will be

```
LondoPage 20160301.pdf
```

I need to filter the files with the date in the end of filename. i.e, if i pass date '20160301' the mentioned file should select.

Comment: So, you have getfiles( .. *.pdf) if theres a date specified, change the *.pdf to "*20160301.pdf"

Comment: @BugFinder. How can i generalize it if there are 100 files?

Comment: It still says *<something>.pdf it is general.. I dont understand your question.. you have answers all providing you ways to do it. putting the <date>.pdf at the end would always give you our answer

Comment: Or are you really asking how to insert <date> into the file name in your getfiles? eg you dont know how to add a variable into the string

Comment: I think that may be his question @BugFinder, you should post it as an answer and I'll remove mine

Comment: @BugFinder... No. My files are coming with <filename> <date>.pdf format. Now i need to get the files which have <date>part  that give as as input . I think it makes sense

Comment: Then you've had that, 3 times over..  Are you really asking how to add in your example 20160301 into a *.pdf string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var date = "20160301";
string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(EnvSettingsTools.FilePath.ToString(), "*.pdf")
                             .Select(path => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path))
                             .Where(f => f.EndsWith(date))
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Rather than contains, use EndsWith

Comment: Thanks! It's quite tricky to understand what is actually required here

Answer (score 1):

This will get files whose name ends with date you pass for filter:

```
var date = "20160301"; 
string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(EnvSettingsTools.FilePath.ToString(), "*.pdf")
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
                                     .Where(f => f.EndsWith(date))
                                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand your desired outcome but I will do an educated guess that you need to be able to order or filter the folder content. That can be achieved in more than one way. I will propose a solution to your problem

```
     if (!Directory.Exists(pathToFiles)) return;

     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pathToFiles);
     FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
     var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);

     var filteredFileByDate = orderedFiles.Where(f => f.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().Split('/').Last().Contains("filterText"));
```

With the ordered files you will receive all files ordered by a particular property, in this case I have chosen the creation date.

With the filtered file you will receive a collection of one or more files that mach your criteria. The more precise is your criteria the less results you get.

Hope that it helps ;)